# Photo wont appear in tkinter despite global declaration

Tags: python, tkinter

Hello I am building a tkinter app and need to open photos within a function. Upon research I saw that you need to make the image = to a variable to keep track of it and use global. Despite doing these things my image still wont show up
can anyone help??
Here is my code

```
#when one of the catagory buttons is pressed this func is called opening a new window with
#a button for all images
def open_catagory(button_name):
    fourth_window = Toplevel()
    global fourth_pics
    global fourthview
    global CC
    fourth_pics = (
        "C:\\Users\\link\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\python stuff\\screenshot example\\Snapshots by catagory\\"+ str(button_name))
    CC = [f for f in listdir(fourth_pics)]
    print(CC)
    fourthview = Image.open(
        fourth_pics+"\\" + str(CC[-1]))
    fourthveiw = fourthview.resize((800, 800), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    fourthveiw = ImageTk.PhotoImage(fourthveiw)

    fourth_window.config(height=1800, width=1800, bg="chocolate1")
    fourthw_picture_box = Label(fourth_window, height=800, width=800,image = fourthveiw)
    fourthw_picture_box.place(x=800, y=100)
    count = 0
    x = 1
    y = 0
    catagorypath = "C:\\Users\\link\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\python stuff\\screenshot example\\Snapshots by catagory\\" + str(button_name)

    for g in listdir(catagorypath):
        count += 1

    for I in listdir(catagorypath ):
        screenshot_snap = Button(fourth_window,text = str(I), bg =  "chocolate3",activebackground = "white",padx= 80,pady =10)
        screenshot_snap.grid(column = 4, row = int(x),rowspan = 5,columnspan = 5,padx = 50,pady =10)
        x += 10
        if y < count:
            y += 1
```

Comment: ```fourthveiw = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=fourthveiw)``` Try this

Comment: Are you aware you have one variable spelled `fourthview` and one spelled `fourthveiw`?